# User Input not compare to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, match

I am trying to get total answers if user input correct answer in the field. But it always return 0 not sure why. Can you help me to fix it please where i am wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Match It</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Set Verbs in correct form</h1>
<p>
<table>

            <tr>

                <th scope="col">Match 1</th>

                <th scope ="col">Match 2</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>one</td>

                <td>two</td>

                <td><input type="text" id="answer1" value=""></td>

                <td>four</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>eleven</td>

                <td><input type="text" id="answer2" value=""></td>

                <td>thirteen</td>

                <td>fourteen</td>

            </tr>

    </table>

                <button onclick="readit()">Check Answer!</button>

    <p id="p2"></p>

</p>

Hint: twelve or three
<script type="text/javascript">

//array

var verblist =[];

verblist[0] = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

verblist[1] = ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"];

var verdi = verblist[0][0];

function readit() {

var verb1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;

var verb2 = document.getElementById("answer2").value;

//control input

var CorrectAnswer = "0";

if(verb1.toUpperCase() == verdi[0][2])

{

    CorrectAnswer++;

}

if(verb2.toUpperCase() == verblist[1][1])

{

    CorrectAnswer++;

}

document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = ("You given total " + CorrectAnswer + " Correct Answers.");

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just check please and help me fix it, i tried different ways but for me it always showing the 0 in return.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many issues in your code.
For example, `var verdi = verblist[0][0];` The value of `verdi` would be "one" but you are trying to index int0 it in the line: `if(verb1.toUpperCase() == verdi[0][2])`

Also, this line `if(verb2.toUpperCase() == verblist[1][1])` will cause problem.
Since, uppercase value of anything entered in the input box will never match `verblist[1][1]`

These are the things that you can begin to fix first.

Answer (score 0):

toUpperCase should be toLowerCase and your verdi variable isnt an array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Match It</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Set Verbs in correct form</h1>
 <p>
  <table>

   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Match 1</th>
    <th scope ="col">Match 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="answer1" value=""></td>
    <td>four</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>eleven</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="answer2" value=""></td>
    <td>thirteen</td>
    <td>fourteen</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <button onclick="readit()">Check Answer!</button>
  <p id="p2"></p>
 </p>
 Hint: twelve or three

<script type="text/javascript">

 //array
 var verblist =[];
 verblist[0] = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
 verblist[1] = ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"];

 function readit() {

  var verb1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;
  var verb2 = document.getElementById("answer2").value;

  //control input
  var CorrectAnswer = "0";

  if(verb1.toLowerCase() == verblist[0][2]){
   CorrectAnswer++;
  }

  if(verb2.toLowerCase() == verblist[1][1]){
   CorrectAnswer++;
  }

  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = ("You given total " + CorrectAnswer + " Correct Answers.");
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```